# Move files which uses content type to another SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, sharepoint-library

I created a SharePoint library in which I made a column named DocID . After uploading the document, the value of DocID automatically shown in the document due to content type.

But When I move or copy this document to another library, the data of DocID is not shown.

How can I move this document with DocID?

[image: Please consider the below output]

Answer (score 0):

While you are copying or migrating documents from one library to another, along with their metadata values, make sure the structure of both the source and target libraries is the same. In other words, the source and target libraries should have the same set of columns. In your case, make sure the "**DocID**" columns exist in the target library and are mapped to the right content type. Then, you will not face this problem.

Comment: both library contains the same columns, but I am facing this problem.

Comment: What is the type of the column you are using in "DocID"?

Comment: Single line of text. should I have to add content type in both library?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the content type as well - please see my answer description. :-)

Comment: data is not shown in the document but the data is added in column

Comment: Can you add screenshot?

Comment: please consider my screenshot and if you need more info, let me know

Comment: As per the screenshot, both the source and target document libraries have the same DocID, so I am not understanding the problem. Please elaborate more.